# Excluding a file from UNIX "find" results based on existence of another file

Tags: unix, find, unix-utils

I have a big bunch of directories, each with a series of .pdf files. Some of these files have successfully converted to .csv, some have not. An example directory listing using `find ./`:

```
./test5.pdf.csv
./test6.pdf
./test1.pdf.csv
./test3.pdf
./test1.pdf
./test3.pdf.csv
./test4.pdf.csv
./test7.pdf
./test2.pdf
./test5.pdf
./test4.pdf
./test2.pdf.csv
./test8.pdf
```

*How would I return a list of files that have **not** successfully converted?*

In other words, what are the files that don't have a .csv.pdf counterpart?

In this example, it would be test{6,7,8}.pdf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how it works with find:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" | while read F; do test -f "${F}.csv" || echo "$F"; done
```

Using find is preferable to shell globbing as it has no limitation on the number of arguments and it works with spaces and special characters.

Comment: Rad, this is totally what I was looking for. Just tested it, works great!

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a way to do it with `find` directly, but it's very easy using a for loop:

```
for file in *.pdf; do [ -f ${file}.csv ] || echo $file; done
```

If you need to run it at the top directory and have it recurse, you could use find like this:

```
for file in $(find . -iname '*.pdf'); do [ -f ${file}.csv ] || echo $file; done
```

which would output something like this:

```
./dir2/test7.pdf
./dir2/test6.pdf
./dir2/test8.pdf
./dir3/test7.pdf
./dir3/test6.pdf
./dir3/test8.pdf
./dir1/test7.pdf
./dir1/test6.pdf
./dir1/test8.pdf
```

Careful with that last one though, if you aren't sure there won't be any strange characters in the input filenames, make sure you set [IFS](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html#WEIRDVARS) environment variable accodingly:

```
OFS=$IFS
export IFS=$'\n'
```

Of course, from here on it only gets nastier.

I'm assuming you use bash.

Comment: This is a great, detailed answer if you have a less-than-stellar version of `find` (I think it's a bit different on Solaris) or don't like `find` -- I accepted the other answer because it's closer to my initial question, but this one is pretty terrific as well. Wish I could accept both!